# Stuck on creating a java interface

Tags: java, interface

I have created a Registry class which is used to add and delete students to a register, also incorporating a Student class. Now I have to build an interface with a main menu, where there are 4 options to choose from including; add a student, delete a student, print the register, and quit. Where a scanner will be used to decipher which option the user selects.

I'm really not sure how to go about creating this, I have been given a template to fill in, but cant get my head around it. Additionally, as my RegistryInterface does not have a main method, I then have to create a RegistryApp, which i also have a template for.

Any help/advice on how to go about creating this would be much appreciated, i am completely new to interface building sorry!

RegistryInterface code template:

```
import java.util.*;
public class RegistryInterface {

private Registry theRegistry = null;

public RegistryInterface(Registry theRegistry){}

//Displays the main menu and gets valid option from user

public void doMenu()
{
    System.out.println("Registry Main Menu");
    System.out.println("****************** \n");
    System.out.println("1. Add a Student");
    System.out.println("2. Delete a Student");
    System.out.println("3. Print Registry");
    System.out.println("4. Quit");
    System.out.println("Select option [1, 2, 3, 4] :>");    
}


private void doAddStudent() {}


private void doDeleteStudent() {}


private void doPrintRegistry() {}

}
```

RegistryApp code template:

```
public class RegistryApp {
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    //Create the registry object
    Registry theRegistry = new Registry();

    //Create an interface
    RegistryInterface aRegistryInterface
            = new RegistryInterface (theRegistry);

    //Display the menu
    aRegistryInterface.doMenu();
}

}
```

Comment: A class is not the same thing as an interface. Are you sure it shouldn't be `public interface RegistryInterface`?

Comment: We were given this template by our lecturer

Comment: By Interface, do you mean GUI? Just have `System.out.println()` statements with the different options you want to offer. Like it appears you already have. Take user input with `Scanner` object.

Comment: I am pretty sure he means a GUI considering he is talking about menus and menuoptions.

Comment: Yeah i think you might be right, it was just referred to as an interface in my assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Your `RegistryInterface` is a class and not an interface

- An interface must be declared like this `public interface`
- It should contain only declaration of attributes and methods to use and should not contain ANY implementation
- You have to create a class (like `RegistryImpl`) that implement this interface and its methods
- To use it, you just need to create an instance of your interface (like `RegistryInterface RI = new RegistryInterface(R);`)

Comment: Right ok, when i change it to public interface, i get error messages thrown from every line where i have set my methods to private, why is this?

Comment: @JoePerkins interfaces are meant to be implemented. You can't and shouldn't have a private method there.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might help:

```
public interface RegistryInterface {

  //Displays the main menu and gets valid option from user
  public void doMenu();

  public void doAddStudent();

  public void doDeleteStudent();

  public void doPrintRegistry();

}
```

Registry:

```
public class Registy implements RegistryInterface {

    //java will force you to write methods the same as the ones declared in
    //RegistryInterface...
}
```

Main class:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
  //Create the registry object
  RegistryInterface theRegistry = new Registry();

  //Display the menu
  theRegistry.doMenu();

   //etc...
```

}

Answer (score -1):

It seems you are talking about Graphical User Interfaces, if you are completely new to java GUIs there is a very elaborate tutorial on http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/

Comment: Look at the output, he's printing command line things there. Swing has nothing to do with command line user interfaces.